# How to detect pro-sex behavior on an open chat platform?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

Many chat channels (e.g. Omegle, mIRC) produce the the following conversations when engaging a person one doesn't know.

> M
> asl?
> F 25
> wonna sexchat?

This behavior is extremely prevalent. Detection of nudity in videos or images is an open research problem. What I am listing here should be simpler to accomplish. Any off-the-shelf solutions? Any language and any open and free library is fine(including papers on how to do it)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library on `Python` that name is `profanity`. Link: [profanity-check](https://pypi.org/project/profanity-check/)
With machine learning algorithm I'm super sure that we can handle it easily. For that you should collect whole words as that. After collecting, you can add a label line, like 0 if acceptable, 1 if not. Then, with some successful machine learning algorithms, you can associate the data with the `euclidian`, `manhattan` type distance criteria and create a decision mechanism about whether the content is bad or not. It is difficult to predict how much the success rate will be, but I think that with such an approach, a success rate close to 90% can be achieved. I would like to share with you an academician whose work I trust on this subject. [Yılmaz Kaya](https://scholar.google.com.tr/citations?user=X4UhzLAAAAAJ&hl=en)

Comment: SO is weird sometimes, closing legitimate questions and stuff. Thank You for the on-point and timely advice!